# Array in angular service is reset to zero when go to the another page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I faced with strange problem, I try to create shopping cart. I did it by [this guide](https://angular.io/start/start-data). But in my case I have a problem that shopping cart reset to zero when I comes to cart component. Here is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CartService} from "../../Services/CartService";
import {Product} from "../../Models/Product";
import {CartItem} from "../../Models/CartItem";

class Item {
  product: Product
  productAmount: number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  public productsInCart: CartItem[];

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.cartService.getProductsInCart().length)
    this.productsInCart = this.cartService.getProductsInCart();
  }

}
```

Here I'm getting `CartService`

```
import {Product} from "../Models/Product";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CartItem} from "../Models/CartItem";

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  private readonly productsInCart: CartItem[] = [];

  addToCart(product: Product, amount: number) {
    this.productsInCart.push(new CartItem(product,amount))
  }

  getProductsInCart() {
    return this.productsInCart;
  }

}
```

And in ahother component i have a button that adds product to my cart

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-success p-2" (click)="addProductToCart(product)"
         *ngIf="product.isAvailable == true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>Buy
      </a>
```

So, when I click on this button, product adds to cart and all is ok because I logging into console cart size, but when i try to come to CartComponent - my array becomes empty and logges zero. Can someone help me? [Link do DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-owyppe?file=src/app/cart/cart.component.html)

Comment: Create a working example in https://stackblitz.com/ to show this behavior. This will help with debugging and identifying a solution.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-owyppe?file=src/app/all/all.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-owyppe?file=src/app/all/all.component.html) it looks part of the issue is simply your routing. You are using `href` with `<a>`. When the user clicks on that "Cart items" link, it refreshes your entire Angular application, wiping away the saved cart items stored on `CartService` property `productsInCart`. Change:

```
href="/cart"
```

to:

```
routerLink="cart"
```

You can see in this [forked example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u77fez) that by making that simple change, you can choose some cart items then click on the cart link and see the added objects are available because the application was not reloaded as it was with `href`. You want to make sure you are using `routerLink` instead of `href` for navigating within your application (defined routes) or use `Router` or `Location` to navigate.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Omg that was so simple. Thank you a lot, you really help me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

what you need is something called state management, to understand more about this topic
I share with you these links to understand well this side of the application state in angular:

[angular-state-management](https://medium.com/@2muchcoffee/angular-state-management-a-must-have-for-large-scale-angular-apps-8b98e5a761c7)

[What is the application state? Theoretically, it is the entire memory of the application...](https://dzone.com/articles/angular-app-state-management-with-ngrx)